# jquery submit not working when migrating to higher version

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i just migrated from jquery 1.10.2 to 1.2.1 in order to use tablesorter.js addon, but my problem is that my jquery ajax post is not working anymore with this jquery version, i hope someone can figure out the problem or what im missing, here is my code:

js file

```
// variable to hold request
var request;
// bind to the submit event of our form
$("#postAtencion").submit(function(event){
    // abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);
    // let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    // serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/atencion",
        type: "post", 
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(response){ 
        // we have the response
        $('#tableSubView').html(response); 
        }
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console
        console.log("Atencion Posted");
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Jsp File

```
<div class="container">
        <h2>Consulta</h2>
        <form id="postAtencion" style="padding:19px;">
        <div>
         Number: <input type="text" name="msisdn" style="margin-left: 15px;" class="inputAtencion">
        </div> 
         Init Date: <input type="date" name="fechaInicio" class="inputAtencion">
         Final Date: <input type="date" name="fechaFin" class="inputAtencion">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="buscar"/> 
        </form>
    <div id="tableSubView"></div>

    </div>


    <script src="js/file.js"></script>
    <script src="js/atencion-post.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-requiered.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1.2.1 was released in 2007?

Comment: 1.10.2 to 1.2.1 is going backwards.

Comment: hmm really, ok lol nevermind, sorry im kinda new using jquery

Comment: Now this is a great question that you don't see very often. Where do you even find 1.2.1 these days ?

Comment: there http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.1.min.js

Comment: Try jQuery 1.8 or 1.9

Comment: We are using jquery 1.10.2 with tablesorter just fine.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it appears to be about a misunderstanding of jQuery version numbers. OP says the issue is solved.